# MATLAB - Solving a multivariable constraint optimization

Tags: optimization, matlab

I have a system of three unknown, let's say `x`, `y`, `z`. I want to solve the following nonlinear system:

```
f1(x,y,z) = 0
f2(x,y,z) = 0
```

Since I have 3 unknown, but 2 equations, I want to result to have say `z` maximized.

And there are the three constraints:

```
x > 0
y > 0
z > 0
```

How can I solve this problem? To summarize:

- I have 3 unknowns
- I have 2 equality equations, and 3 constraints
- I want 1 of the unknowns to be as large as possible

**Edit**

This is what I have done so far with the `fmincon`:

```
% objective function 
% Want to minimize the function 1/z (so maximize the variable)

function f = objFun(arg)
x = arg(1);
y = arg(2);
z = arg(3);

f = 1/z;
end

% My two nonlinear equalities f1, f2
function [c, ceq] = NLPart(arg, someInput)
% dont want to get into the detail of the equation since it is
% very long, but at the end:
x = arg(1);
y = arg(2);
z = arg(3);

c = 0;

% The equations below are dummy. they are just some nonlinear combination of the three 
ceq(1) = x*y*z;
ceq(2) = x/y + z^2;
end
```

Then in MATLAB, I ran the following:

```
system = @ (arg) NLPart(arg, [1 2 3]);
obj = @ (arg) objFun(arg);

fmincon(obj, init_state, [], [], [], [], [0 0 0], [], system);
```

This gave me the following error:

> Error using svd Input to SVD must not contain NaN or Inf.
>
> Error in pinv (line 29)    [U,S,V] = svd(A,0);
>
> Error in qpsub (line 463)
>                       projSD = pinv(projH)*(-Zgf);
>
> Error in nlconst (line 618)
>           [SD,lambda,exitflagqp,outputqp,howqp,ACTIND] ...
>
> Error in fmincon (line 794)
>       [X,FVAL,LAMBDA,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,GRAD,HESSIAN]=...

BTW, my objective `1/z`, I want it to equal to zero (by maximizing `z`). I don't know if I have written this right

Comment: Did you try using `linprog`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html . Also, placing your systems here would be awesome as we can recreate your problem and can solve it.  BTW, I answered a couple of your questions in the past, but you haven't accepted any answers.... not pushing, but I'm just curious if I have helped you at all.

Comment: My system is nonlinear so I can't use that! As for the equations, they are quite large, and I need to give quite a bit of background. It should be enough to say that I have a system of 3 unknowns, with 2 equality equations, 3 constraints, and I want one of the unknown to be as large as possible!

Comment: You didn't specify they were non-linear.  Here you go: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/unconstrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to do an optimization where your objective function is defined by:

```
h(x,y,z) = z;
```

with the following non linear equality constraints:

```
f1(x,y,z) = 0;
f2(x,y,z) = 0;
```

And the following lower Bounds:

```
x > 0, y > 0, z > 0
```

Yes, you can do this in MATLAB. You should be able to use 'fmincon' in the following syntax:

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[],nonlcon)
```

x0 is a three element vector and the result will also be in the same format which will give you the values for x,y and z. Take a look at the documentation of fmincon for more details:
 http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html

Comment: Just to be clear, my objective function `h(x,y,z) = z` is the same as the `fun` that shows up in `fmincon()`?

Comment: Yes you can create an anonymous function handle in the call to fmincon like this:
    x = fmincon(@(x)x(3),x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[],nonlcon)

Comment: I can't get this to work! I updated my question, with the error that MATLAB is giving me

Comment: I think `1/z` could cause issues, minimize `-z` instead